# How to weight paint the skeleton with muscles

Tags: weight-painting

I bought a human skeleton model with muscles. It has a lot of bones and different muscles. I want to place the model into certain position to show an exercise and hide all the muscles that are not active in the exercise. Then export the .jpg and use as a photo. The skeleton is very realistic.

My problem is that the ribs deform badly when I move the arm from T to A position. Is there a way to fix the ribs so they won't deform?

On the picture can be seen deformation of left ribs and right ribs are normal, because the right arm is in T position.

The developers of the model said, that the solution is Weight Painting.
Normally in videos they select the rig, then the mesh, then go to weight paint mode and then you are able to control control click the bones and that activates vertex groups.
But that doesn't work for me. (Maybe to problem is that each bone/muscle is it's own mesh?) I try and in object mode select the Rig, shift select the mesh (ribs) then go to weight paint mode and the ribs are blue. That's fine but I don't know what to do next, so that when I move the arm from T to A position that the ribs wont deform badly.Also, the bone that deforms badly (Skeletal_Ribs) has 68 Vertex Groups (like arm_stretch.l, arm_stretch.r, c_arm_twist_offset.l.) if that helps solve my problem...
I rigged the the skeleton with Auto Rig Pro addon (I added so called reference bones/meta rig, matched to rig - which created rig for me, binded/skinned/weighted - by pressing the bind button).

Anyone knows how to do the weight painting of my model?

All the best, Anže

[image: Ribs deform badly]